# getting value from another sub in VB

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vba

I have this Sub which does the calculation get the information from CSV file.

```
Private Sub getTotalAmt(intDuration As integer, strProgrameType As String)
```

I've another Sub:

```
Private Sub getMembershipDiscount(ByRef dtDOB As Date, dblTotalAmt as Double)
```

which calculates the age of the customer and based on their age, gives them discount. So to do this, I've got to get the total amount from the above Sub (`getTotalAmt`) to this Sub procedure.

My question is, how to receive total amount from that sub procedure?

Answer (score 3):

by definition, subroutines don't have output.
Instead, you want to write a function.  In your case, change the code you have to something like this:

```
private function getTotalAmt(intDuration As integer, strProgrameType As String) as double
     'do the same maths you do in the sub, and store your answer in a variable called "whatever" 
     getTotalAmt = whatever
end function
```

then to use the function:

```
sub IUseFunctions()
   dim myDiscount as double
   myDiscount = getTOtalAtm(1,"s")
end sub
```

In this example case, I've decided for you that the discount value is stored in a double type number.  You can change that to whatever you like, at the top line of the getTotalAmt function.

Comment: You beat me to it :)
To add to your answer, you can also return a specific datatype, if the program calls for it.

Ex:
 
        Function NameOfFunction(byval num1 as integer, byval num2 as      integer)
        dim x as integer = num1 + num2
        return x
        end function

Answer (score 2):

Please speicify return types and convert your Sub to a Function
In that way you can  always return something from your Functions, 
if you specify a return type to your `getTotalAmt(int Duration As Integer, StrProgrameType As String)` method , That would be look like this `Function getTotalAmt(int Duration As Integer, StrProgrameType As String) As double`

then from another method you can call it and use retuned value of it for further calculation or whatever.

**i.e**

```
Private Sub sub1() 

//You use the Sub2's value in here like 
msgbox(sub2) 

End Sub 

Private Function sub2() As String //You can specifiy any data type you are returning, I specified String just for demnostrate

//Set the value of Sub2 in here
 sub2 = "Yourvalue";

End Function
```